# Login and registering not working on live server

Tags: php, jquery

This is the link to my site:

```
http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/index.php
```

Oddly, I just can't get into the admin's dashboard page after uploaded into live server. I've no idea why I just can't get through this login and registering function.

I made sure the data exists in the database. And noticed in the network tab that the pages are accessed but just not working! In console tab error is thrown but I've no idea on how to fix them.

Could somebody help me fix this please. You may try login with with following:

email: admin@gmail.com
password: admin

Or you may try creating a new user!

Thanks a lot for this!

My login script:

```
 /*login user*/
 <!--login form submission starts-->
$("document").ready(function () {
  $("#login-user").submit(function () {
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "login-this-user.php",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(data[i].email);
          console.log(data[i].activate);
          console.log(data[i].status);

          if ($.trim(data[i].status) == '0') {
            //alert("not verified");
            $('.invalid-popup-link').trigger('click');

          } else {
            //alert("verified");
            location.replace("admin/dashboard.php");

          }
        } //end for

      },
      error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
 <!--login form submission ends-->
```

Errors found in console tab f12

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at e.extend.parseJSON (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:11020)
>       at cc (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2:1382)
>       at w (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4:11263)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4:17218)

LATEST ERROR
Error thrown after replacing with jquery version 2.1.4

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at n.parseJSON (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:5497)
>       at ub (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:7521)
>       at x (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10935)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b (http://210.48.154.18/~econtrax/ezy/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14765)

Comment: For one thing, jQuery 1.7 is ancient. Use a current version of jQuery.

Comment: @EdCottrell I changed to 2.1.4 version still cannot I've update the errors thrown this time in my post

Answer (score 2):

I tried by Replacing

```
error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

with

```
error: function (errorThrown) {
```

There was no error in console and output was

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: " ", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token `e` - is starting of your message from java controller, that comes from the server instead of valid JSON string. Try to return something parseable:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: $activated_id=array();
foreach($profile as $k=>$v){
array_push($activated_id,array("email"=>$v['email'],"activate"=>$v['activate'],"status"=>$status));
 $_SESSION['email'] = $v['email'];
 $_SESSION['activated_id'] = $v['activate'];

}
echo json_encode($activated_id);

Comment: I parsed like above but responseText return empty but in localhost works...Do you know why please?